# leaflet map bounds meteor

Tags: meteor, leaflet

I have a leaflet map in meteor project with polygns on it. I set the bounds like that:

```
 var map = L.map('map', {
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    maxBounds: maxBounds,
    minZoom:2,
    maxZoom:16
}).locate({setView: true, maxZoom: 16});
```

maxBounds is a nested array:

```
var maxBounds= [[31.838389, 35.223155],[31.807467, 35.260148]]
```

I want to expand the bounds but whenever I do that and get the zoom out, the polygons are getting messy.. What can I do to solve that?

Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Can you show some screenshots of your "messy" polygons at least? Then how you "expand the bounds"?

Answer (score 0):

change your array for this:

```
var southWest = new L.LatLng(31.838389, 35.223155),
    northEast = new L.LatLng(31.807467, 35.260148),
    maxBounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
```

> More info:
>
> http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds
>
> http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlngbounds